# Yahoo - imap_open()

Tags: php, laravel, imap, yahoo

I don't found right answer, how to connect yahoo imap mail server. Other connection works (gmail, outlook, hotmail), but yahoo not.

```
imap_open("{imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "email_address", "password");
```

Error exception:

Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] AUTHENTICATE Invalid credentials (errflg=1)

I tryed without novalidate-cert, but nothing.

Comment: Use out of the box mail functionality https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#introduction. Stop using raw functions like `imap_open` and use framework brewde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution

Click the "Allow apps that use less secure sign in" switch

https://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Mozilla-Thunderbird-for-Yahoo!-Mail

Comment: It changed a bit now you have to add an application password and use it instead of the account password.